# Grails SubFlow doen't render its view page and returns HTTP 404

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin, spring-webflow

I am using **Grails 2.3.6** with the **WebFlow 2.0.8.1** plugin installed. I am trying to get a proof-of-concept working with a SubFlow. After reviewing the example SubFlow [documented here](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.3/guide/single.html#subflowsAndConversations), I am having difficulty getting a simple SubFlow to work.

**Note:** I am a new comer to Grails and WebFlow in general.

This is my project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

`HelloController` renders this page:

[image: HelloController Page]

`DemoController` renders this page:

[image: DemoController Page]

However, when I click the **Go To Sub Flow** button on the HelloController's page, I get a 404:

[image]

If I supply `/hello/hello/subflowDemo.gsp`, the page renders but it is not the page from `DemoController`.

What am I doing wrong?

**HelloController**:

```
package helloworld

class HelloController {
    def helloFlow = {
        hello {
            on("goToSub").to "subflowDemo"
        }
        subflowDemo {
            subflow(controller: "demo", action: "demo")
        }
    }
}
```

**hello.gsp**:

```
<html>
<body>
    Hello world!
    <g:form>
        <g:submitButton name="goToSub" value="Go To Sub Flow" />
    </g:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**DemoController**:

```
package helloworld

class DemoController {
    def demoFlow = {
        demo {
        }
    }
}
```

**demo.gsp**:

```
<html>
<body>
    This is the demo screen!
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to complete the Flow Cycle. I believe subflow's state cannot be the end state for the Main flow. So End the flow in the main flow.

The following code changes worked for me,

HelloController.groovy

```
class HelloController {

    def helloFlow = {
        hello {
            on("goToSub").to "subflowDemo"
        }
        subflowDemo {
            subflow(controller: "demo", action: "demo")
            on("gotomainflow").to "endstate" // have a transition to endstate

        }
        endstate {

        }
    }

}
```

endstate.gsp in views/hello/hello/endstate.gsp

```
<html>
<body>
    Came Back to main- endstate
</body>
</html>
```

DemoController.groovy

```
class DemoController {
    def demoFlow = {
        demo {
            on("gotomainflow").to "gotomainflow" //have the transition which calls a event
        }
        gotomainflow() // this event will trigger the event in the main flow
    }
}
```

demo.gsp in views/demo/demo/

```
<html>
<body>
    This is the demo screen!
    <g:form>
        <g:submitButton name="gotomainflow" value="Go To Main Flow" />
    </g:form>
</body>
</html>
```